# Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I have a dataframe column which contains URLs. I want to extract a specific string  out of this URL by using a regex pattern for each row. Here is an example of the URL string:

*'www.abcdef.com/sports-bra-sports-bra-black-abcde1f02-c11.html',*

As a column is a series and I need to iterate through, I've tried the following codes:

**1.**

```
for i in df['landing_screen_name']:
    regex = i.str.extract(r'.{0,13}.html')
    print(regex)
    break
```

**2.**

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    a = row['landing_screen_name'].str.contains(r'.{0,13}.html')
    print(a)
    break
```

however for both I got the following error:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

I've tried everything but couldn't find the issue yet, could you please help me with this?

Comment: try your code without `.str`

Comment: Then I have the following error:AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extract' 
or same error with 'contains'

Comment: The purpose of methods like `.str`, `.extract` etc. is that they *work on entire columns of the DataFrame* and *handle the iteration for you*. If you are writing your own loop (which you shouldn't normally do when working in Pandas), then you end up with e.g. `row['landing_screen_name']` being **a string**, which you work with *the same way that you would work with any other string*, as if you had never heard of Pandas.

Comment: That's why the error message tells you `'str' object has no attribute` etc. In general, you should learn how to read and understand error messages, and draw conclusions about what they are telling you about the code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The reason why I used the loop methods above is I wanted to try on the first value and see if it works, since not every row has the URL and I have to create a condition for it on the next step. 

And yes, I haven't heard pandas (nor python) until 3-4 months ago and still struggle. You can just ignore simple questions like this if you are annoyed by them, instead of throwing hate on them

Comment: There is nothing hateful about what I said. I am pointing out to you how to solve problems for yourself, which is an expected skill for programmers. I didn't say anything about your level of experience, either; what I said is that if you have a string, you should expect to work with the string in the ordinary string-like ways, and Pandas is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['landing_screen_name'] = df['landing_screen_name'].str.extract(r'(.{0,13}\.html)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should operate at the column level, e.g. use:

```
print(df['landing_screen_name'].str.extract(r'.{0,13}.html').to_string(index=False))
```